# Could not resolve module @angular/core

Tags: angular

I'm building an Angular 5+ library.  The project is based on the structure of [angular-quickstart-lib](https://github.com/filipesilva/angular-quickstart-lib).  When I run the build script, I get an error stating that @angular/core could not be resolved.

```
Error: Error: Could not resolve module @angular/core
at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolByModule (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:31884:30)
at StaticReflector.findDeclaration (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:30371:63)
at StaticReflector.initializeConversionMap (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:30636:36)
at new StaticReflector (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:30317:14)
at Object.createAotCompiler (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:32125:44)
at AngularCompilerProgram._createCompiler (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:404:37)
at AngularCompilerProgram.get [as hostAdapter] (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:323:22)
at AngularCompilerProgram._createProgramWithBasicStubs (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:435:73)
at AngularCompilerProgram.initSync (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:377:27)
at AngularCompilerProgram.get [as tsProgram] (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:353:22)
```

Digging a little further into "node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js", the error seems to come from "this.host.moduleNameToFileName".